# what's the data type of a string inside the double quote in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
void main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

I'm not allowed to make any change to the above main function while the output on the screen need to be sth like:

initialize
Hello World
clean up

My thought is that I need to use overloading operator of `<<` . However I need to know what's the data type of the double quoted string following the operator `<<` , otherwise I will not make full use of my redefined `<<` operator. Anyone any thought?

Comment: @HansPassant Not even a pointer, but an array; i. e. `const char [LENGTH + 1]`. Yes, const. Const in C++, non-const in C.

Comment: Hint, try the following `int a = "uh-uh";` The compiler error message holds the answer. If it doesn't, it needs to be replaced for a more effectual version.

Comment: Re *I'm not allowed to make any change to the above main function* -- does that include the atrocious `void main`?

Comment: @DavidHammen: And the lack of `#include <iostream>`, without which the compiler won't recognize `cout` or `endl`? (You also need `using namespace std;` or, better, a `std::` prefix on each one.)

Comment: The lack of `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` (yech) is the key to solving this problem. Well, that and the nasty `void main`.

Comment: @Hans Passant: In C++ (and the questions is tagged [C++]), string literal is actually const-qualified. Your remark about missing `const` is specific to C. And indeed it is not a pointer but rather an array `const char[N]` (`char [N]` in C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redefine `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const char*)`. There's one **huge** problem with this approach: It is undefined behavior. The standard library already defines that function, and you are not allowed to redefine standard library functions.

The key to solving this problem is to recognize that `cout` is in the global namespace. The solution is simple: Write your own class that overloads `operator<<` and make a global variable named `cout` that is an instance of this class. That way you are not running into undefined behavior.

You'll also need to do something with that `endl` that is in the global namespace.

Your code should look something like

```
// Insert your code here.

int main () {
   cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

Since this looks like homework, I'll leave the rest up to you.

Comment: You don't redefine it with this signature. The StdLib function is a template, so this custom version would even be preferred if it is found using unqualified lookup. (Putting the overload in the std namespace is not allowed.)

Comment: @DyP: I am not a language lawyer, but my take on 17.4.3.1, *A program may* **add** *template specializations for any standard library template to namespace std. Such a specialization (complete or partial) of a standard library template results in undefined behavior unless the declaration depends on a user-defined name of external linkage ...* is that (1) It is illegal to change something in the standard library and (2) The additions have to involve a user-defined type. Anything else is UB. Adding is OK, subject to those qualifications. Changing is UB.

Comment: @DyP: Re *You don't redefine it with this signature. The StdLib function is a template, so this custom version would even be preferred if it is found using unqualified lookup.* `std::ostream` is not a template. It is a template instantiation, `typedef basic_ostream<char> ostream`. Overloading `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const char*)` is exactly what you are talking about, I think, and my take on the standard is that doing this is illegal. Then again, I might be reading too much into the word "add".

Comment: 17.4.3/1 (17.6.4.2.1/1 in C++11) is about restrictions on *namespace `std`*. It essentially prohibits adding anything but a template specialization depending on a user-defined type *to namspace `std`*. There are no restrictions in this paragraph to functions in the global namespace. `std::ostream` is not a template, yes, but `basic_ostream` is, and the function that's defined in the StdLib is `template<class traits> basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>&, const char*);` (the most specialized version), see [lib.ostream.inserters.character]/2-3.

Comment: (The idea is to define this function in the global namespace where it can be found using unqualified lookup, and will be preferred because it's ranked equal to the StdLib overload but is not a template. [Here's a live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/676fa60ec45c0e61), though it segfaults. Running it on my local computer works fine. That smells like UB, but I'm quite sure it's not.)

Comment: indeed i couldn't redefine the operator since everything is standard here. I need to avoid using #include <iostream> and using namespace std. I'd rather to redefine cout as object of my own class so i can make use of it.

Answer (score 4):

The type of the literal is "array of {suitable number of} const chars", but a better approach might be to have some kind of global object.

(Adding an overload for the array would probably not even work, because the existing overload for `char const *` would be getting in the way.)

Comment: *const chars if I'm not mistaken. And good point about the XY problem.

Comment: @H2CO3: Yeah, thanks. A bigger problem is that the decay-to-pointer would create an ambiguous overload.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. Damn unconditional implicit conversions (one more time).

Answer (score 2):

The type of a string literal is `char const[n]` where `n` is the number of characters in the string literal, including the terminating null character. Note, however, that the solution to your problem isn't overloading `operator<<()`. Instead, you should look at constructors, destructors, and variable with static live-time.